# Will get_current_user_id() in wordpress fire a database request?

Tags: wordpress

I am using `get_current_user_id()` and `wp_get_current_user()` multiple times in my plugin. Are these functions going to send a database request everytime I use them or is the user object of the current user always available (cause wordpress requests it anyway on initializing)?

Would it be better to declare a global var at the start of my script with the current user info?

```
<?php
global $currentUser;
$currentUser = wp_get_current_user();

function function1() {
    global $currentUser;
    echo $currentUser->ID;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will not. It will read the wordpress global variable `$current_user`